# Is It Possible to Match This Handwritten Brooklyn Font with LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, scripts

I would like to match, if possible, the following handwritten font:

[image]

[image]

I was hoping that Latex offers it, but I could not locate it.

QUESTION: Is this particular font available with Latex; perhaps via a different name? Or, does anyone know where it is available for free (without signing up for a "free-trial"). It is available for a cost, which I would like to avoid.

Thank you.

Comment: use luatex and use that font if you have it: you don't need special "tex fonts"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't have the font; I was hoping to obtain it gratis.

Comment: this site suggesets free fonts https://www.whatfontis.com/FB_Brooklyn-Script.similar or just search for free handwriting font although beware most "free font" sites are unethical.

Comment: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/oesterreichischeschulschrift/ is the closest I could see.

Comment: Thank you @PaulA

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for providing this link. Incidentally, and I don't doubt what you say, but I had thought that, perhaps, if a site specified, say, "free for commercial use,'' it was OK to download the font and use it freely.

Comment: If it says that it may well do. Most "free font" sites say nothing or say "downloader's responsibility" and whatever it says, if a font (or anything) is being sold by its creator, but offered for free by someone else, the chances are it's stolen. It's like buying TV cheap from the bloke in the pub, it's only cheap if you don't ask where it came from.

Comment: Thank you again @DavidCarlisle.